# Get innerHTML of #document-fragment instead of textContent

Tags: javascript, html, css, contenteditable

I have a contenteditable p tag. When the content from the p tag is extracted, and inserted into the other tag, all the markup of the original is lost. Is there any way to save the markup?

Please note if the **caret is @ the i-th** position in the paragraph, then the **characters are extracted starting from that position till the end**.

```js
function select() {
    var el = document.getElementById('p');
    el.focus();

    var sel = window.getSelection();
    var selRange = sel.getRangeAt(0);

    var range = selRange.cloneRange();
    range.selectNodeContents(el);
    range.setStart(selRange.endContainer, selRange.endOffset);

    document.getElementById('other').innerHTML = (range.extractContents().textContent);
    // return range.extractContents().textContent;
}
```

```css
p {
 background-color: #eee;
}

.red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<p id="p" contenteditable="true">This is <i>a</i> <span class="red">paragraph</span> <b>with</b> lots of markup.</p>
<p id="other"></p>
<button onclick="select()">SELECT</button>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`range.extractContents()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range/extractContents) returns a [`DocumentFragment`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment).

`DocumentFragment` doesn't have an [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) property. `innerHTML` comes from the [`Element`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) interface, while [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) is part of the [`Node`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node) interface. `DocumentFragment` inherits from `Node`, but not `Element`.

This means you could just append the entire fragment because it's a `Node`:

```js
function select() {
  var el = document.getElementById('p');
  el.focus();

  var sel = window.getSelection();
  var selRange = sel.getRangeAt(0);

  var range = selRange.cloneRange();
  range.selectNodeContents(el);
  range.setStart(selRange.endContainer, selRange.endOffset);

  //document.getElementById('other').innerHTML = (range.extractContents().textContent);
  var frag = range.extractContents();
  var i;
  var node;
  var other = document.getElementById('other');
  other.innerHTML = '';
  other.appendChild(frag);
}
```

```css
p {
 background-color: #eee;
}

.red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<p id="p" contenteditable="true">This is <i>a</i> <span class="red">paragraph</span> <b>with</b> lots of markup.</p>
<p id="other"></p>
<button onclick="select()">SELECT</button>
```

Comment: Please refer to the question again. There has been a minor change.

Comment: @dorado, found an easier way, just append the entire fragment.

Answer (score 6):

For further reference, If anyone actually need the innerHTML of the extracted fragment.

The fragment have Children Nodes and those have the `outerHTML` property, so you simple have to get the `outerHTML` from all childNodes

```
const fragment = range.extractContents();
const htmlContent = [].map.call(fragment.childNodes, x => x.outerHTML).join('')
```

the `map.call` part is needed because although the fragment has the `childNodes` property, the `childNodes` doesn't have the `map` method.

Comment: And if there are text content

`const htmlContent = [].map.call(fragment.childNodes, x => x.nodeType === x.TEXT_NODE ? x.textContent : x.outerHTML).join('')`

Comment: A small readability improvement (imo) for the second line:  `Array.from(fragment.childNodes).map(x => x.outerHTML).join('');`

Answer (score -2):

Didn't you mean something like this ?

```
document.getElementById('other').innerHTML = el.innerHTML;
```

Your javascript then would be as simple as:

```
function select() {
    var el = document.getElementById('p');
    el.focus();

    document.getElementById('other').innerHTML = el.innerHTML;
}
```

---

**EDIT:**

Hey, you down voted my answer but can you explan what you want to achieve? The code i wrote above you can see working in this jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/936zuzky/1/

You want to save original markup - it's saved so what do you want to achieve ?

Comment: That downvote has not been made by me. As for the context, what I want is that the HTML be copied starting from the caret's location to the end and be placed in the other paragraph. You can see that in the accepted answer.